# Incorrect array data returning from Linq query expression

Tags: c#, linq

See i have this following code below, at line no.9 i'm calculating some dates to move forward, so im using `AddDays` method but in return i'm getting all dates same for all rows.

If i do `AddDays(6)` like this then it is returning correctly by moving all dates by 6 days.

How should i do it for adding days according to my logic at this point.

```
[DataContract]
public class JQGridRow
    {
        [DataMember]
        public long id;
        [DataMember]
        public object[] cell;
    }
   var sortedItems = invBatch.ListOfItems.OrderBy(i => i.RunDateIndex);//This will return IEnumerable<Class> List

DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(lblStartDate.Text);
JQGrid.JQGridRow[] rowData = (
        from i in sortedItems
        select new JQGrid.JQGridRow() {
        id = i.ID,
        cell = new string[] { 
        i.ID.ToString(),
        i.Status.ToString(),
        i.StatusTitle,
        i.RunDate.AddDays((startDate.Subtract(i.RunDate)).Days+1).ToString(Utility.DATE_FORMAT),
        //Here in above line the array returning same values for all columns of this row        
        i.StartTimeString,  
        i.EndTimeString, 
        i.EndTime.ToString(), 
        }}).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, or why you feel it's a good idea to call `DateTime.Parse` repeatedly rather than just once... a short but complete program which got rid of *everything* you're not interested in would make this a lot clearer.

Comment: i'm sorry that i didn't ask my question more clearly, i want an array which contains an `ID` & `Collection of Rows`. Now for each row i want date to move forward by xyz days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dates are all same and equal the next day after `startDate` because you calculate them as such.

```
i.RunDate.AddDays((startDate.Subtract(i.RunDate)).Days+1)
```

Rounding to whole day, you compute RunDate+(startDate-RunDate+1) = startDate + 1. `i.RunDate` does not matter.

Comment: No dates are not same, see if i do this way `i.RunDate.AddDays(6).Days)`, and if suppose `sortedItems` contains 4 rows, i get 4 rows with different date and those dates are added i.e forwarded by 6 days.

Comment: yes, because when you add 6 days you do not subtract the original date. rundate-rundate = 0, so you always work only with the startdate

Comment: @FosterZ: If you just specify constant 6, yes, dates will be different. What is your intention here?

Comment: @pinusnegra: i didn't get you, please explain more

Comment: suppose i have 4 dates `11/12/2011,12/12/2011,25/12/2011,27/12/2011` now `startdate='5/2/2012'`, now i want the 1st date from above 4 dates to move to '5/2/2012' and 2nd to '6/2/2012' and so on...

Comment: @FosterZ ok, an example (let's forget these are datetimes): runDate = 2, startDate = 5. you do this: runDate + (startDate - rundate + 1), so: 2 + (5 - 2 + 1), which is 6. Take another runDate: runDate = 3. 3 + (5 - 3 + 1) = 6. got it?

Comment: @FosterZ then you are missing an information: which one from the 4 dates is your reference date to arrange the others? ok, in this example it's 11/12/2011, but how you decide it?

Comment: @pinusnegra: oh my god, i'm such an idiot... thanks a ton man

Comment: 11/12/2011 is not decided, it comes from the list `sortedItems`